# Does anyone know which おり this is?

Tags: grammar, politeness, expressions, て-form

> 彼女は表情が生き生きとしておりとてもかわいい。

was translated awkwardly on ALC as

> She is very pretty for the liveliness of her expression.

Which おり is this? I think I know it from the polite しております　but is it here wielding more expressive meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me have a go at this:

> - 彼女{かのじょ}は: She/Her (establishing context)
> - 表情{ひょうじょう}が: expression (with nominative case marker)
> - 生{い}き生{い}き: vividly, lively
> - して: Verb conjunctive form of する
> - おり： 連用形 of　**居る{おる}** (To be/exist for animate things) This should be the verb you're looking for
> - とても: intensifier
> - かわいい：　pretty

1. The verb is 生き生きとして居る, the subject is 表情. Combining them yields "There is a vivid/lively expression"
2. Context is 彼女

   Combining 1. and 2. yields "For her, there is a vivid lively expression"

Now put the verb in 連用形 to get:

> 3.`彼女は表情が生き生きとしており`

**One of the uses of the 連用形 is to join up several sentences as subphrases into a large continuous sentence.***

One sentence has been established, which is in 3.`彼女は表情が生き生きとしており`

The other sentence is `とてもかわいい` ((She) is very pretty)

Combining them yields  "She has a lively expression, she is very pretty"

---

EDIT:
Regarding your comment on trying to introduce a "because" nuance.

You can use the　て-form of the verb to introduce an implicit sequence of events. (Weak causal relation)(If you want a stronger causal relation, use から)

See [Verb Grammar - The Verb Conjunctive Form](http://www.nihongoresources.com/language/lessons/lesson-03/lesson.html)(You have to scroll down a little bit)

The difference between linking sentences with て-form and　linking with 連用形 is that there is no implicit sequence of events when linking with 連用形.

---

*Extracted from [nihongoresources](http://www.nihongoresources.com/language/lessons/lesson-03/lesson.html#grammarv):

> One of the uses of the 連用形 is to join up several sentences as subphrases into a large continuous (which is what 連用 means) sentence, similar to how in English for instance you would join up two sentences by putting a comma between them and if necessary changing the phrasing on the first sentence just a tiny bit. If we look at an example you might get an idea of how this works:
>
> 日本語：　花が咲く。
>   English: Flowers bloom.
>
> 日本語：　鳥が鳴く
>   English:　Birds are chirping..
>
> 日本語：　春が来た。
>   English:　Spring has come.
>
> We can combine these into a single sentence:
>
> 日本語：　花が咲き鳥が鳴き春が来た。
>   English:　Flowers bloom, birds are chirping; spring has come.

Comment: I realised I did not properly deal with 生き生き`として`, I'm　not sure how して relates to the と particle. But it seems adverbial to me. I'd like someone to correct/verify this and/or provide good English parsing for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the provided translation it is implied that she is pretty/cute because of her lively expression, while in your translation what is pretty/cute is her expression. Which do you think is more correct? My initial impulse was to assign the おり with something of a "because" twist to it, as I've seen this pattern as you've described it, acting as a comma.

Comment: It should be "she's very pretty" since she's the one marked by は. Think of it as combining 彼女は表情が生き生きとして居る。 with 彼女はとてもかわいいです。 I will edit my translation to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My very loose translation is "What a lively expression she has...she's so cute!"

Answer (score 9):

It replaces the verb stem `い` (of `いる`) for morpho-phonological reason.

The construction in your example uses a verb stem to continue another predicate after it as in:

> よく食べ、よく寝る。 [Vowel verb stem 'tabe']
>   年月が経ち、忘れてしまった。  [Consonant verb stem 'tat' followed by the epenthetic vowel 'i']

When you use the verb `いる` in this construction, its stem 'i' is very short that some people don't like it, and may even consider it ungrammatical:

> 生き生きとしてい、とてもかわいい。

Those people replace `i` with a longer verb stem `or`, which can be considered in present Japanese a variant of this verb stem:

> 生き生きとしており、とてもかわいい。  [Consonant verb stem 'or' followed by the epenthetic vowel 'i']

When it is followed by an affix, the shortness of the stem is compensated by the affix, and it does not sound bad, so both forms are allowed:

> ...しています。
>   ...しております。

**Translation**

The translation that you got is a good one for a literal translation.

> 彼女は表情が生き生きとしており、とてもかわいい。
>   　'As for her, the facial expressions being lively, she is very pretty.' (Literal)
>   　'Her facial expressions are lively, which make her very pretty.'  (Natural)

Comment: your answer is way better, it explains why いる becomes おる even though they're both 居る.

Comment: thank you, Sawa. Would you have a take as to a better translation for the sentence?