# Help with adverbs with とする and としている

Tags: grammar, translation, adverbs

Taking [yadokari's sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3334/542):

> 彼女は表情が生き生きとしておりとてもかわいい。

The part that I need help understanding is the relation of `生き生きとして` with　`表情`　and　`居る`.

Looking up the dictionary entry for `生き生き`, it is "an adverb taking the `と` particle"

**(Question 1)** Does the adverb modify `して`? Or is `生き生きとして` treated as an adverb as a whole?

**EDIT**: What is the difference between `1. 生き生きとする` and `2. 生き生きとして居る`?

**(Question 2)** Is `2.` the `~ている` construction of `1.`? And what is its significance when used with an adverb? English parsing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「生き生きと」 is the adverb. 「して」 is the ～て form of 「する」.

> "vividly do"

Of course, you need the 連用形 that follows in order to translate it completely, as is given in your other question.

**EDIT:**

Yes.

> 居る いる
>   (v1,vi,**uk**,aux-v) to be (of animate objects); to exist; to stay; (after the -te form of a verb) verb indicating continuing action or state (i.e. to be ..ing, to have been ..ing); (P)

Same as without the adverb. Only with the adverb instead.

> "be vividly doing"

Comment: how do you parse "facial expression that is vividly doing"? My gut feeling says it's not the progressive aspect but the stative aspect.

Comment: You can't, which is why you can't translate literally. "vivid facial expression"

Comment: Is it the same use of ~している　in "私は長い足をしている" (I have long legs)? Then "彼女は表情が生き生きとしている" would be "She has vivid facial expressions".

Comment: Sure, but instead of modifying 「している」 by <noun>+を, you're modifying it by an adverb.

Comment: It makes sense to "have a noun as an attribute". But it's quite hard to understand to "have an adverb as an attribute". Possibly cause I'm thinking in English and not in Japanese.

Comment: @Flaw: I think the thing you're up against here is that する isn't always "do". It's also a state. For example, you can say 匂いする, which you *could* in a way, translate as "doing a smell", but in English we would just say "smelling". Likewise, here you have "doing a vivid expression", which in English we would say more like "expressing vividly". Personally, I'd go with "vivacious expression".

Comment: After the helpful input on my original question, I've ended up with this very loose english translation:  "What a vivacious expression she has...she's so cute!" I tried to make this as colloquial an english expression as I could. What I would like to know is this: to me, the original japanese expression seems like something one would say aloud in spoken japanese.

Comment: cont.-  Yet in all the ways we have tried to translate it into english ( perhaps with my last attempt being an exception), the sentence has ended up sounding like something one would only see in written english- one would rarely say aloud "what a lively expression she has!" ... it would seem more natural just to say "what an expression" or "look at that expression". So, is the original Japanese sentence a spoken colloquial example, or a more literary one?